# Python module not found error "No module named 'ortools' "

Tags: python, or-tools, modulenotfounderror

I'm new to python and or-tools.
I'm trying to run this [sample program](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#python_9) from Google OR-Tools.

I've installed or-tools by `python -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools` and copied full script from the link, and added `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and did `chmod +x tsp.py`.

After running the script, this error showed up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tsp.py", line 5, in <module>
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools'
```

First, I thought this is because PYTHONPATH, so did :

```
export PYTHONPATH="./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools"
```

But the error text didn't changed.
If anyone knows what it cause, help me please..
Thank you

-----------UPDATE-----------------------

After I got comments, I ran `python -m site`
This is showed up.

```
ros@ros-dynabook-R734-M:~/tsp$ python -m site
sys.path = [
'/home/ros/tsp',
'/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/ros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/ros/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/ros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

I also went to ~/python2.7/site-packages/ and ~/python3.6/dist-packages/, but there is no ortools module..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add to your question the output from running ``python -m site``. Also if you're running using python3, don't export Python 2 packages... Finally the PYTHONPATH should be the parent directory holding all the packages i.e. ``./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/``. Try all these and update your question accordingly.

Comment: if you are running with python3, you should do `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools` instead

Comment: Thank you for all comment and advise.
I will do it and update it asap.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install 'OR-Tools' by `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools` to use in python3.
And also PYTHONPATH should be the parent directory of the packages which is `./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Now the script seems running correctly.